# Why is 1 the derivative of $x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can someone explain to me why the derivative of $x$ is 1. We just started derivatives in my calculus class and I don't understand it at all.

Comment: Leave the self-deprication at your desk. I realise this probably won't help you much, but it's better than nothing. Let $f(x)=x$, for all $x\in \Bbb R$. Then, by definition of $f'$, $$f'(a)=\lim \limits_{x\to a}\left(\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\right)=\lim \limits_{x\to a}\left(\dfrac{x-a}{x-a}\right)=\lim \limits_{x\to a}\left(1\right)=1,$$ for $a\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Guys, try to show him using limit $\rightarrow 0$

Comment: Never mind, see above

Comment: To put Git Gud's comment in words, the derivative of a function at a point $a$ is the limit of slopes of the secant lines which bound sections of the graph that are progressively smaller and contain $(a,f(a))$. However, since $f(x)=x$, every secant line has slope $1$, so your limit is naturally going to evaluate to $1$.

Comment: Your statement is imprecise.  $1$ is the derivative of $x$ *with respect to* $x$. ($\frac{dx}{dt}$ is the derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$, and so on.)

Comment: @Andrew Rimel : This is equivalent to Git Gud's comment and you can pick which version you prefer: By definition of the derivative, $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x+h-x}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}1=1.$$ For this function the derivative is a constant (1): usually it will depend on $x$.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative tells us the slope of a line. The function $y(x)=x$ is a line with slope $1$. So if the derivative is to make any sense and actually tell us the slope, the derivative of $x$ should be $1$.

In general, for functions that look like $x^n$, their derivatives are $nx^{n-1}$, i.e. move the power out in front and reduce the power by $1$.

Comment: Well, some care is needed here: the derivative *at some fixed point* is the slope of a rather special line, the tangent line to the given function **at that fixed point** ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Very true, I was more answering specifically to the case given while trying to be as simplistic as possible. Obviously, I was a bit loose with my language.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the graph of $y = x$; it is a line with slope 1. If $f$ is a function, then $f'(a)$ is the slope of the line tangent to $f$'s graph at $a$.  In this case, the only way a line can be tangent to a line is if it is the line itself.  Hence 
if $f(x)= x$,
$f'(x) = 1$ for any $x$.

Answer (score 0):

There's this formula to find derivatives of monomials, like $x^3$ and $5x^2$. What you do is you multiply the term by its power, then subtract the power by $1$.

so, $x^2$ becomes $2\cdot x^{2-1} = 2x$

Just apply that to $x$, which has a power of $1$. Remember that any number to the zeroth power is equal to $1$.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please see my edit on how you can use LaTeX to format your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You ask why the derivative of the function given by $f(x)$ is $f'(x) = 1$. The proper answer is found in the definition. Given a function $f$, the derivative is defined as
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.
$$
So if $f(x) = x$, then
$$\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\color{blue}{f(x+h)} - \color{red}{f(x)}}{h} \\ &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\color{blue}{x + h} - \color{red}{x}}{h} \\ &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\color{blue}{h}}{h} \\ &= \lim_{h\to 0} 1 = 1.
\end{align}
$$
Now this tells you exactly why the derivative of the function given by $f(x) = x$ is the constant function $1$.

If you want a way to *think about it*, then remember that the derivative of a function at a number $x$ is the slope of the tangent line to the graph at the point corresponding to $x$. And if you sketch the graph of the function given by $f(x) = x$, then you get a straight line with slope $1$. So at any point, then slope of the tangent line is, in particular, equal to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power rule for finding the derivative that,$$\frac{dx^n}{dx}= n x^{n-1}.$$
We know that $x$ is the same thing as $x^1$, and use the above power rule, you get $\frac{dx}{dx}=1 x^0$ and we also know that $x^0$ is $1$, so $\frac{dx}{dx}=1 * 1=1$.

The integral is $$\int x^n dx= \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$
So the derivative of $x$ is one and the integral of $dx$ is $x$.  If you want to go little different, you can use this formula for finding the derivative, $$\frac{d f(x)}{dx}=
\lim_{h\rightarrow0}⁡ \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$$ you can substitute $x$ in $f(x)$ and still you will get one.

Comment: You should use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to make your maths look pretty. (Actually, I've done these edits myself, so you can see what they look like. Also, do you really mean "the integral of $dx$ is $x$"? Surely you mean "the integral of $1$ with respect to $x$", as $dx$ should be read as "with respect to $x$".)